# How to load two storage objects for singelton class

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

I want the constructor value : `metisobjectStorageClient` to be loaded with metisMediaStorage in the controller class and I want the constructor value `uimObjectStorageClient` to be loaded with `uimMediaStorage`  in the controller class.

So that when I try to access the service class from controller class, I should be able to access it with the different storage credentials through `metisMediaStorage` and `uimMediaStorage`.

```java
@Component
public class Configuration {

    @Value("${metis.thumbnails.s3.key}")
    private String metisThumbnailS3Key;
    @Value("${metis.thumbnails.s3.secret}")
    private String metisThumbnailS3Secret;
    @Value("${metis.thumbnails.s3.region}")
    private String metisThumbnailS3Region;
    @Value("${metis.thumbnails.s3.bucket}")
    private String metisThumbnailS3Bucket;
    @Value("${metis.thumbnails.s3.endpoint}")
    private String metisThumbnailS3Endpoint;

    @Value("${uim.thumbnails.s3.key}")
    private String uimThumbnailS3Key;
    @Value("${uim.thumbnails.s3.secret}")
    private String uimThumbnailS3Secret;
    @Value("${uim.thumbnails.s3.region}")
    private String uimThumbnailS3Region;
    @Value("${uim.thumbnails.s3.bucket}")
    private String uimThumbnailS3Bucket;

    @Bean
    public ObjectStorageClient metisobjectStorageClient() {
        return new S3ObjectStorageClient(metisThumbnailS3Key, metisThumbnailS3Secret, metisThumbnailS3Region, metisThumbnailS3Bucket, metisThumbnailS3Endpoint);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectStorageClient uimObjectStorageClient() {
        return new S3ObjectStorageClient(uimThumbnailS3Key, uimThumbnailS3Secret, uimThumbnailS3Region, uimThumbnailS3Bucket);
    }
}

@Service
public class StorageServiceImpl implements StorageService {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectStorageClient objectStorageClient;

    @Override
    public Boolean checkIfExists(String id) {
        return objectStorageClient.isAvailable(id);
    }

--------other functionalities

}


@Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private MediaStorageService metisMediaStorage;

    @Autowired
    private MediaStorageService uimMediaStorage;

}
```

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please referer [how to ask a good qustion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It's a bit unclear to be honnest, but I think that you're looking for [Named bean](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/inject-bean-by-name.html)